# Set a global git pre-received.d hook

Tags: gitlab

On gitlab server, i have created a global custom hook "**extension_autorisation**" in (**/etc/gitlab/custom_hooks_dir/pre-receive.d/extension_autorisation**) and it is written with **#!/bin/env bash**.

And i have added the line ( **gitlab_rails['custom_hooks_dir'] = '/etc/gitlab/custom_hooks_dir/pre-receive.d/extension_autorisation'**)
in the file "**gitlab.rb**" that is in (**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**).

Then running **sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure**.

But when i push to a repository, nothing happens!

I have tested by putting it directly in a repository and it works ex. image:
[test push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgiUM.png)

And the custom hook is owned by git end executable :

drwxr-xr-x 3 git git 4096 17 sept. 17:20 custom_hooks_dir

drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4096 17 sept. 17:20 pre-receive.d

-rwxr-xr-x 1 git git 3622 17 sept. 16:56 extension_autorisation

Any help please ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Robert

Answer (score -1):

i have found the problem in the config. line.

it must be (**gitlab_shell['custom_hooks_dir'] = '/etc/gitlab/custom_hooks_dir/'**)